# Clear timeout set in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, settimeout

I've got in trouble trying to clear a timeout set in an object, I have an object like this:

```
var banner=function(options){

    this.s_btn=options.s_btn;
    this.interval=null;

    this.pos=0;
    this.maxPos=4;

    var _obj=this;

    _obj.s_btn.bind("click",function(){
        //clear Timeout
        clearTimeout(_obj.interval);
        _obj.interval=null;
        //Change banner with some FX
        _obj.changeBanner($(this).index());
        //start timeout Again
        _obj.setInt();
    });
    //Function that starts timeout
    this.setInt=function(){
        _obj.interval=setTimeout(function(){
            //where slide to change
            var to=(_obj.pos==_obj.maxPos)?0:Number(_obj.pos)+1;
            //Change banner with some FX
            _obj.changeBanner(to);
            //starts bucle
            _obj.setInt();
        },_obj.time);
    }
    _obj.setInt();
}
```

There are two methods:
- changeBanner: it changes the image of a banner
- setInt: it starts a timeout loop which executes the changeBanner function each X milliseconds.

Also I have bound the click event to an element; I want to reset the timeout loop but I'm doing something wrong. :S

I store the timeout function inside this.interval and I clear it when I click on the element called before.

Comment: Misspelling an accident or cause of error?         `clearTimeout(_obj.inerval);`

Comment: I found that :S I fixed it, anyway it doesn't work yet

Comment: And of course you have made sure the "click" is actually called?

Answer (score 0):

you spelled interval wrong in the example

clear timeout(_obj.inerval)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by refering the setTimeout and the clearTimeout to the window:

```
window.setTimeout(_obj.interval)
```

and

```
window.clearTimeout(_obj.interval)
```